# How to fix 'tar: Failed to set default locale' error?

Tags: r, macos, locale, tar

I'm trying to install a package into R, something I swore on my blood never to do, yet here I am.

The command supposedly goes:

```
install.packages('NCStats',,'http://www.rforge.net/')`
```

while I am enjoying the healthy dose of:

```
Warning: dependencies 'nortest', 'plotrix', 'sciplot', 'car', 'gplots', 'gdata', 'Hmisc', 'TeachingDemos' are not available  
trying URL 'http://www.rforge.net/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.11/NCStats_0.1-4.tgz'  
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 237120 bytes (231 Kb)  
opened URL  
=================================================="  
downloaded 231 Kb  
tar: Failed to set default locale  
The downloaded packages are in
    /var/folders/Qj/Qjps7xnxFcWdSHsJY3lo+k+++TI/-Tmp-//RtmpzNO8MM/downloaded_packages`
```

Le-sigh. Anybody know how I can tell tar what locale I'm in, not that I understand why it needs that or why it can't just know it already?

I'm running OSX 10.6.4 and R 2.11.1 GUI 1.34 Leopard build 64-bit (5589).

Comment: For starters, how about trying to satisfy the noted *Depends* you do not seem to have on your box?

Comment: what do you get returned from `Sys.getlocale()` ?

Comment: Ack, too bad Joris, I forgot to check that before I tried the answer below, but I suspect it was Icelandic or something, since that's what my system preferences are. Dirk, since this package doesn't work after that command, it's unusable, I'm not going to navigate some labyrinth of dependancies.

Comment: Why would you swear you never would install a package?

Comment: 10 years ago it was a pain (as you can see). Now it's much nicer, and my blood has boiled off.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Step 1 (In R Console)

```
system('defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8')
```

Step 2: Restart R

Source: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Internationalization-of-the-R_002eapp

Comment: Thank you, that works. To be 100% clear, that command is copy pasted into the Terminal, not the R console, and then the R console needs to be restarted.

Comment: Worked for problems with the rJava package too.

Comment: This didn't work for me on OSX 10.9.5. I am actually on a German computer and so `echo $LANG` returns **de_DE.UTF-8**. I tried this in place of _en-US.UTF-8_ and also your answer exactly as-is - neither had any effect.

Comment: Please edit this answer to tell people to quit and restart R.

Answer (score 24):

Use this command in the R console:

```
system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
```

Remember to quit and start again R.

Answer (score 9):

refer: https://github.com/nerves-project/nerves/issues/376#issuecomment-456939623

If you don't want to permanently set env. variable. do:

```
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_ALL=$LANG
```

No need to restart the system.

Comment: Works well. No restart required. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Better Close the entire R studio and Reopen it again
  will fix that error tar: Failed to set default locale