# R error You're using a non-UTF8 locale, therefore only ASCII characters will work

Tags: r

I am getting the error message above when I open R.

When I attempt to download a package I am also given this error message:

```
tar: Failed to set default locale
```

Can anyone tell me how to set a UTF8 locale on R?

Comment: I can't help, but I suspect you need to say what operating system you're on.

Comment: And possibly where you are on the planet (or at least where your computer thinks you are).

Comment: Please post the output of `Sys.getlocale()`.

Comment: Please see this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907719/r-fail-install-packagesncstats-http-www-rforge-net-tar-failed-to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689104/installing-r-on-mac-warning-messages-setting-lc-ctype-failed-using-c
this one gives the right answer     Open Terminal
Write or paste in: defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
Close Terminal
Start R

Answer (score 1):

```
tar: Failed to set default locale
```

This generally means the locale you have selected (through the LANG and LC_* environment variables is not available on your system).

How you add locales to your systems is distro dependent. On Debian systems you can use "dpkg-reconfigure locales". On Ubuntu I belive it's normally done by installing the corresponding "language pack" package. On other distros I have no idea.