# Installing R on Mac - Warning messages: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"

Tags: macos, r, installation

I would like install R on my laptop Mac OS X version 10.7.3

I downloaded the last version and I double click on it and it was installed, when i start up I get the following error, I searched in internet but I could not solve the problem, any help would be appreciated

the errors are

> During startup - Warning messages:
>   1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
>   2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C"
>   3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C"
>   4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C"
>   5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C"
>   [R.app GUI 1.50 (6126) x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0]
>
> WARNING: You're using a non-UTF8 locale, therefore only ASCII characters will work.
>   Please read R for Mac OS X FAQ (see Help) section 9 and adjust your system preferences accordingly.
>   [History restored from /Users/nemo/.Rapp.history]

Comment: Oh, I just wrote in terminal defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8 and then it solved ( i do not have any message or error) I have another question, how to import my data? where i should copy my data for example if they are in desktop and saved in txt, how can i import them?

Comment: refere these links for details http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Internationalization-of-the-R_002eapp http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/247-system-locale-on-mac-os-x-set-by-default-to-an-utf-8

Comment: The links provided by @AbhishekGayakwad (thanks to him) explains the answer below.

Answer (score 497, accepted):

1. Open Terminal
2. Write or paste in: `defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8`
3. Close Terminal (including any RStudio window)
4. Start R

---

For someone runs R in a docker environment (under root), try to run R with below command,

```sh
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 R
# instead of just `R`
```

Comment: This works for me as well. Thanks! 
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Internationalization-of-the-R_002eapp

Comment: What's going on actually behind this ?

Comment: Does this work in OSX 10.9.1? I get the same warnings except #1 and #5 with R 3.0.2. I installed R by Brew package manager.

Comment: Thanks! @Masi yes it does!
In addition to you Masi, I would highly recommend installing from the CRAN repos. http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html select a mirror that fits you and then pick packages you want to install, it should be pretty straightforward! Good luck!

Comment: Works in OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

Comment: In my system (OS X 10.11 El Capitán) I have environment variables `LANG` and `LC_ALL` set to `en_US.UTF-8` for my terminal (in the `~/.bash_profile` file), and command line R does not display those warning messages; but R Studio does.

Found that R Studio uses the _System Preferences > Language & Region_ settings. Which in my system are: _English_ for the language and _Spain_ for the Region. This leads to a `en_ES` locale, not supported by the system.

Found that I can set an specific setting for Mac R Studio with this command: `defaults write org.rstudio.RStudio force.LANG en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: @RamónGilMoreno It seems that setting the language of R-project solves the problem for both R and R Studio. So I guess it is a better approach.

Comment: @yongwei-wu Yep. Definitely. Setting `org.R-project.R` is the accepted answer. The `org.rstudio.RStudio` setting complements it in the case you (as me) want some locale flexibility on the command line.

Comment: It works for local R but the warning still appears in remote R via ssh which populates those locale variables to remote.

Answer (score 86):

Setting locales in terminal resolved the issue for me. Open the terminal and

1. Check if locale settings are missing

   ```
   > locale
   LANG=
   LC_COLLATE="C"
   LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
   LC_MESSAGES="C"
   LC_MONETARY="C"
   LC_NUMERIC="C"
   LC_TIME="C"
   LC_ALL=
   ```
2. Edit `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`

   ```
   export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
   ```
3. Run `. ~/.profile` or `. ~/.bashrc` to read from the file.
4. Open a new terminal window and check that the locales are properly set

   ```
   > locale
   LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
   ```

Comment: you made my day, that solved the issue of Rstudio too, which reported at https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200651966-Locale-issues-unable-to-start-or-connect-to-Rstudio-server

Comment: When I am running R script to plot `svg` using `Rscript` in bash on osx, I get this warning. Solution: `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and solution: writting `Sys.setenv(LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8")` in script following Bhoom Suktitipat 's answer all work for me.

Comment: You might want to add that if you are running zsh, you need to edit `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: This didn't change the locale in my terminal; only changing `~/.bash_profile` worked correctly; see here for more https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51038/257940

Comment: This solution worked for me as well, on Manjaro Linux with Code warning about missing locales (running R from terminal was fine).

Comment: Nice, that it also works fine on Ubuntu Linux

Answer (score 27):

Just open the R(software) and copy and paste

```
system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
```

Hope this will work fine or use the other method

```
open(on mac): Utilities/Terminal copy and paste

defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

and close both terminal and `R` and reopen `R`.

Comment: Pasting in the Terminal did not work for me, this oneliner did work. It might be because of insufficient user rights.

Comment: Where is the Utilities? Not working in macOS Sierra 10.12.1 :( Can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873359/r-encoding-failing-with-umlauts-such-as-ä-and-ö) on the same issue in OS X?

Answer (score 7):

I found slightly different problem running R on through mac terminal, but connecting remotely to an Ubuntu server, which prevented me from successfully installing a library.

The solution I have was finding out what "LANG" variable is used in Ubuntu terminal

```
Ubuntu > echo $LANG
en_US.TUF-8
```

I got "en_US.TUF-8" reply from Ubuntu.

In R session, however, I got "UTF-8" as the default value and it complained that `LC_TYPEC Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"`

```
R> Sys.getenv("LANG")
"UTF-8"
```

So, I tried to change this variable in R. It worked.

```
R> Sys.setenv(LANG="en_US.UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue on Catalina mac. I also installed the R from the source in following diretory.
./Documents/R-4.0.3

Now from the terminal type

```
 ls -a
```

and open

```
 vim .bash_profile
```

type

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

save with :wq

then type

```
source .bash_profile
```

and then open

```
./Documents/R-4.0.3/bin/R 
./Documents/R-4.0.3/bin/Rscript
```

I always have to run "source /Users/yourComputerName/.bash_profile" before running R scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Tks *Ramon Gil Moreno*.
Pasting in Terminal and then restarting R Studio did the trick:
*write org.rstudio.RStudio force.LANG en_US.UTF-8*

Environment:
**MAC** OS High Sierra 10.13.1 //
**RStudio** version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"

Ennio De Leon

Comment: Writing an answer that merely repeats what other answers already say adds zero value, and is frowned upon. Doubly so when the new answer additionally contains errors.

Answer (score -2):

On my Mac r is installed in `/usr/local/bin/r`, add line below in `.bash_profile` solved the same problem:

```
alias r="LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 r"
```