# picker() from manipulate package with accented characteres

Tags: r, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I'm using the `picker()` function to manipulate a ggplot2 line graph. I have strings with accented characters in the list given to picker. When I select a string with accented characters, `ggplot()` returns

```
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...).
```

The sample code works fine:

```
manipulate(
    barplot(as.matrix(longley[,factor]), 
            beside = TRUE, main = factor),
    factor = picker("GNP", "Unemployed", "Employed"))
```

However, if I adapt the code as follows, `picker()` fails:

```
library(manipulate)

dflongley <- longley
colnames(dflongley)[7] <- "Employé"
Encoding(colnames(dflongley)) <- "UTF-8"

x <- c("GNP", "Unemployed", "Employé")
Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"

manipulate(
    barplot(as.matrix(dflongley[,factor]), 
            beside = TRUE, main = factor),
    factor = picker(as.list(x)))
```

`head(dflongley, 1)` gives this:

```
 GNP.deflator     GNP Unemployed Armed.Forces Population Year Employ<U+00E9>
 1947           83 234.289      235.6          159    107.608 1947         60.323
```

x:

```
[1] "GNP"          "Unemployed"   "Employ<U+00E9>"
```

When "Employé" is selected, NULL is passed by `picker()` to `barplot()` and I get the following errors:

```
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
  need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(w.r) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Any idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689104/installing-r-on-mac-warning-messages-setting-lc-ctype-failed-using-c), and adjusting my system preferences with this command: `system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")`