# Error in DESCRIPTION meta-information

Tags: r, r-package

I'm kind of new in package development in R and I'm not sure if this is a common error. I'm developing a new package which is available on GitHub: https://github.com/jroberayalas/ahnr. I'm using R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) on a Mac with OS X Yosemite [platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)].

When I check the package, I get 1 error with the DESCRIPTION meta-information. It doesn't provide any meaningful details and I'm not sure what does this mean.

Below is the output that I get when I press CMD+Shift+E. What I find strange is that I think the package is checked twice: the first time it says `checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK`, and the second time it says `checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... ERROR`. I do not know if this is the way it should work. I must add that the GitHub repository is stored in my Google Drive folder for storage in the cloud, so I'm not sure if this may cause the error.

```
During the initialization - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
Updating ahnr documentation
Loading ahnr
Setting env vars ---------------------------------------------------------------
CFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic
CXXFLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
Building ahnr ------------------------------------------------------------------
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ  \ 
--no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD build '/R/ahnr' --no-resave-data --no-manual 

During the initialization - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* checking for file '/R/ahnr/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'ahnr':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'ahnr_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz'

Setting env vars ---------------------------------------------------------------
_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_ : FALSE
_R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_: FALSE
Checking ahnr ------------------------------------------------------------------
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ  \ 
--no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD check  \ 
'/var/folders/d0/h1123zw10cl569yx765cpxp00000gn/T//RtmpvxgS8q/ahnr_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz'  \ 
--as-cran --timings --no-manual 

During the initialization - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* using log directory '/R/ahnr.Rcheck'
* using R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
* using platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
* using session charset: ASCII
* using options '--no-manual --as-cran'
* checking for file 'ahnr/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* this is package 'ahnr' version '0.0.0.9000'
* package encoding: UTF-8
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package 'ahnr' can be installed ... OK
* checking installed package size ... OK
* checking package directory ... OK
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... ERROR
During the initialization - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR
checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... ERROR
During the initialization - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 

See
  '/R/ahnr.Rcheck/00check.log'
for details.

R CMD check results
1 error  | 0 warnings | 0 notes

R CMD check succeeded
```

My DESCRIPTION file is very simple:

```
Package: ahnr
Title: R implementation of the Artificial Hydrocarbon Networks
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("Jose", "Ayala", email = "#####@##.#", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: This packages implements the algorithm to create artificial hydrocarbon
    networks for data modelling.
Depends:
    R (>= 3.3.0)
License: GPL-3 | file LICENSE
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports:
    matrixcalc,
    pracma
Suggests:
    testthat
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
URL: https://github.com/jroberayalas/ahnr
BugReports: https://github.com/jroberayalas/ahnr/issues
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've seen issues before with the `Decription: ` being on two lines. Try it without the carriage return after 'hydrocarbon'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I put the Description in a single line, but the error persists. The output I get is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DKangeyan, it seems that the problem was related to the LOCALE features within R. I follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510093/4099259) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Internationalization-of-the-R_002eapp), and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to writing R extensions manual https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file, you should avoid mentioning the name of your package or even the word package. You can try without `This package` in the beginning of your description. It should solve the issue for you, because I don't see any other problem with it.

Comment: I made the correction that you suggested, but the problem persists.

Comment: jroberayalas Can you provide your new description and the error that you are getting

Comment: These error messages might not be related to your description file, it could be something with your system. Check out this question from stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689104/installing-r-on-mac-warning-messages-setting-lc-ctype-failed-using-c

Comment: Thanks a lot, DKangeyan. It seems it was a problem with the R software and the LOCALE features. I followed the link you suggested, and then this link as well: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Internationalization-of-the-R_002eapp, and that solved the issue. I'm not an expert on this, and it took a while, but I really appreciate your help!