# R: checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ERROR

Tags: r, cran, r-package

this is my question. I am trying to submit a package in CRAN. When I run the command in console

```
R CMD check MYPACKAGE
```

but I receive the next log, the main error says DESCRIPTION meta-information:

```
* using log directory ‘/Users/Userx/Desktop/MYPACKAGE.Rcheck’

* using R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)

* using platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

* using session charset: UTF-8

* checking for file ‘MYPACKAGE/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK

* this is package ‘MYPACKAGE’ version ‘0.1.0’

* package encoding: UTF-8

* checking package namespace information ... OK

* checking package dependencies ... OK

* checking if this is a source package ... OK

* checking if there is a namespace ... OK

* checking for executable files ... OK

* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK

* checking for portable file names ... OK

* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK

* checking whether package ‘MYPACKAGE’ can be installed ... OK

* checking installed package size ... OK

* checking package directory ... OK

* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... NOTE

Checking should be performed on sources prepared by ‘R CMD build’.

* checking top-level files ... OK

* checking for left-over files ... OK

* checking index information ... OK

* checking package subdirectories ... OK

* checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... OK

* checking R files for syntax errors ... OK

* checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK

* checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK

* checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK

* checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK

* checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK

* checking dependencies in R code ... OK

* checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK

* checking replacement functions ... OK

* checking foreign function calls ... OK

* checking R code for possible problems ... OK

* checking Rd files ... OK

* checking Rd metadata ... OK

* checking Rd cross-references ... OK

* checking for missing documentation entries ... OK

* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK

* checking Rd \usage sections ... OK

* checking Rd contents ... OK

* checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK

* checking examples ... OK

* checking PDF version of manual ... OK

* DONE

Status: 1 NOTE

See

  ‘/Users/piahuerta/Desktop/IMPACT.Rcheck/00check.log’

for details.
```

Do you have any idea how it fixed it? This is my DESCRIPTION file

```
Package: MYPACKAGE
Version: 0.1.0
Date: 2016-06-12
Title: This is my MyPaCKAGE
Authors@R: c(person("John Lenon","Developer",role=c("aut","cre"),email="johnlenon@johnlenon.mx"))
Author: John Lenon [aut,cre]
Maintainer: John Lenon <johnlenon@johnlenon.mx>
Depends: R(>= 3.1.0)
Description: This is my package that I want to submit to CRAN.
License: GPL (>= 2)
Encoding: UTF-8
NeedsCompilation: no
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing it slightly wrong. Instead of

```
R CMD check MYPACKAGE
```

rather do

```
R CMD build MYPACKAGE                   # creates tarball
R CMR check MYPACKAGE_0.1.0.tar.gz      # tests via tarball
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check if the environment variables LC_ALL and LANG are set, see [Installing R on Mac - Warning messages: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689104/installing-r-on-mac-warning-messages-setting-lc-ctype-failed-using-c) if in doubt.