# Coming together with ``\Sexpr{}'' from knitr package, Chinese character garbled

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I created a dynamic ".rnw" file with knitr package. The file contains some Chinese characters. The document works fine when the inline output function ``\Sexpr{}'' is not included in the script.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
sessionInfo()
mp <- mean(pressure$pressure)
@
平均值
\end{document}
```

And the output of the script is:

```
## R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
## Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
## Running under: OS X 10.12.1 (Sierra)
##
## locale:
## [1] C
##
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base
##
## other attached packages:
## [1] knitr_1.14
##
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] magrittr_1.5 tools_3.3.1 stringi_1.1.2 stringr_1.1.0 evaluate_0.10

平均值
```

But if I used the inline output function ``\Sexpr{}'' to print out the results, the Chinese characters become garbled. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
mp <- mean(pressure$pressure)
@
平均值=\Sexpr{mp}
\end{document}
```

And the output becomes:
    < U+5E73>< U+5747>< U+503C>=124.3367053

Comment: Could you include your `sessionInfo()` in the post?

Comment: With Rmd this is no problem ... I just tested this.

Comment: You need to set the correct locale: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9689104/559676

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copyed from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689104/installing-r-on-mac-warning-messages-setting-lc-ctype-failed-using-c)

Type

```
system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
```

and press Enter

Restart R