# How to set locale for Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm unable to get RStudio to correctly identify my locale. The output from `locale` is:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

I changed `LC_ALL` and `LC_MEASUREMENT` from `en_GB.utf8` -> `en_US.utf8` in my `~/.bashrc` based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689104/installing-r-on-mac-warning-messages-setting-lc-ctype-failed-using-c#17510093). However I still get:

```
Beim Start - Warnmeldung:
Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C"
```

Could somebody explain where RStudio tries to read its `locale` settings, and how I can correct this? If I launch `R` from the terminal I don't have this problem, it correctly reads my `locale`. I needed the LC_MEASUREMENT value to be read correct so that I can install a package (`ggbiplot`). (In the end I used the `R` from the terminal to install the package but I'd like to 'fix' RStudio. Thanks.

Info:
R version 3.5.1
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
RStudio: 1.1.463

Comment: Have you tried putting settings into an Renviron or Renviron.site file?  See ?Startup in R for details.

Comment: @user2554330 No I haven't. From reading `help('Startup')` Rstudio `R searches for site and user files to process for setting environment variables.` It seems like this is the case for R but not for RStudio. Do you know how to properly format a `R_ENVIRON` file to point to `locale`? Is there a way to direct it to `~/.bashrc`? Do you know how I can get RStudio to print the locations it searchs for `locale` information?

Comment: The format of the Renviron file is the same as the output of `locale`, i.e. a series of `variable = value` settings, one per line.  As far as I know it needs to be produced before R starts, there's no way to ask R to run `locale`.  No idea about the other questions.