# I get an error when trying to install dkahle/ggmap

Tags: r, google-maps, github, geocode

I tired to run install_github("dkahle/ggmap"), but it seems like there is an error when I try to install the ggmap.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
```

Here is the error message I get in my console when running the install_github code.

```
Downloading GitHub repo dkahle/ggmap@tidyup
tar: Failed to set default locale
tar: Failed to set default locale
These packages have more recent versions available.
Which would you like to update?

1:   mime    (0.5   -> 0.6) [CRAN]
2:   openssl (1.0.2 -> 1.1) [CRAN]
3:   CRAN packages only
4:   All
5:   None

Enter one or more numbers separated by spaces, or an empty line to cancel
1: 5
v  checking for file '/private/var/folders/c2/98cb8xgx7m92m7x7g_ffthy00000gn/T/RtmpiOyVaS/remotes3326374be9c6/dkahle-ggmap-4dfe516/DESCRIPTION'
   During startup - Warning messages:
   1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
   2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
   3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
   4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
-  preparing 'ggmap':
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Removed empty directory 'ggmap/.github'
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'ggmap_2.7.904.tar.gz' (694ms)

Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
Execution halted
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package '/var/folders/c2/98cb8xgx7m92m7x7g_ffthy00000gn/T//RtmpiOyVaS/file332666bc795e/ggmap_2.7.904.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Mac locale issue.

Run `defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8` in Terminal.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510093/9406040)

Comment: It seems like it worked; but it came with another problem. I try to run register_google(key = "my_api_key"), with my API key from google, but i get the error "could not find function "register_google""

Comment: Then you don’t have the GitHub version of ggmap. It’s part of the latest Github release, but not on CRAN.

Comment: How do I get the GitHub version of ggmap?

Comment: @Ola `devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")` (you need to have the devtools library installed)