# How to keep umlaut in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have the following problem and haven't found a solution in the last 3h:

```
test=c("sähköpyörä")
print(test)
```

yields

```
"s\303\244hk\303\266py\303\266r\303\244"
```

However, I should stay "sähköpyörä".

Anyone has an idea how to handle the problem?

I'm running R Studio 1.1.447 on Mac OS X 10_15_3.
Thanks!

Comment: What does `Encoding(test)` return on your computer? What does `cat(test)` print? What version of R is Rstudio using?

Comment: Encoding(test)
[1] "unknown"
cat(test)
sähköpyörä

It's R 3.5.0 - thanks for the fast help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the file with UTF-8 Encoding. I'm running R-Studio 1.2.5042 on Windows and can confirm that this works.

Open your script, goto File->Save with Encoding->[UTF-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4wq8.png).

The next time you open your script, you must first open the file, then click

File->Reopen with Encoding->UTF-8

To Set this globally instead of every time you open the file, goto Tools->Global Options->Code->Saving->[Set default text Encoding to UTF-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKjfJ.png)

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me ;-( Could it be a Mac OS issue? I get the following error message when starting RStudio now:

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C"

Comment: Was all those errors at startup of RStudio? Or while trying to run or load the script? Was the only setting changed the text encoding? While were at it, I would suggest updating your R studio to the latest version via https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download
Oh, and make sure you Clean the Environment, press the "broom" in the Environment tab to "Clear objects from the workspace"

Comment: Upon more research, those error messages do appear to be the result of known problem with R Studio on mac. Try the commands listed here-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689104/installing-r-on-mac-warning-messages-setting-lc-ctype-failed-using-c

Open terminal and type in `defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8` and restart R-Studio

Comment: Thank you freebird! Updating R and RStudio and setting UTF-8 as default worked out in the end!