# Umlaute not displayed correctly with osmdata

Tags: r, openstreetmap, tmap, osmdata

I am having troubles with the German Umlaute (ä, ü, ö) and other signs when using osmdata in R.

I can successfully get the data via query (notice the `Ü` in the bounding box in the first line, it is working fine):

```
#install.packages("osmdata")
#library(osmdata)

bw <- osmdata::getbb("Baden-Württemberg") %>% 
  osmdata::opq(timeout = 25*100) %>%
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(
    key = "admin_level", 
    value = "4"
  ) %>%
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()
```

Having a look at the data, one can see that the umlaute aren't displayed correctly.

```
View(bw$osm_multipolygons)
```

Consequently, searching by "name" doesn't work anymore:

```
dplyr::filter(bw$osm_multipolygons, name == "Tirol")
dplyr::filter(bw$osm_multipolygons, name == "Baden-Württemberg")
```

Tirol is working (no umlaut), Baden-Württemberg (with the `ü`) isn't.

I'm running R on a German Windows 10, R is running in English.

Best regards

Comment: Here is one group that had a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490124/how-to-keep-umlaut-in-r

if you read their comments, suggestions (there is a link to follow at the very bottom too), you may hopefully find a solution to your problem.  

All the best.

Comment: What do you mean with "aren't displayed correctly"? If I run your code and do ``bw$osm_multipolygons %>% as_tibble() %>% filter(name == "Baden-Württemberg")`` I get one row containing the polygon of BW. This can simply be plotted using e.g. ggplot via ``geom_sf()``

Comment: I do not the same result. I get a "Simple feature collection with 0 features and 194 fields". The Ü isn't displayed correctly when I use View(), I get weird looking symbols: Baden-WÃ¼rttemberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current working solution for me is described here:

[Importing Open Street Map data gives wrong encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965831/importing-open-street-map-data-gives-wrong-encoding)

It is really annoying because
a) I am using a function which I don't understand
b) it seems to work for other people (@mrgrund)

on the other side, it seems I am not the only person with the problem.

Best regards