# diagnostic of a bug R CMD check as cran

Tags: r

One of the packages (gdata) my own package (elementR) depends on changed its functions. I adapted elementR to new gdata package. And I have now built and tried to check the package before uploading it on the CRAN.

Although elementR previous versions passed the R CMD check --as-cran always correctly, today it cannot pass the test.
I tried to "translate" the bug (   6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C"     ERROR), but I can't understand what it means.
Could you help me to understand what is bugging ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

```
install.packages("rcmdcheck")
library(rcmdcheck)
rcmdcheck("/home/cha/Documents/Boulot/elementR-version publié/Package/elementR_1.3.7.tar.gz")

── R CMD check ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   During startup - Warning messages:
   1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
   2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
   3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
   4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
   5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
   6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
─  using log directory '/tmp/Rtmpv5TXJD/file1a37e877283/elementR.Rcheck'
─  using R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
─  using platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
─  R was compiled by
       gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
       GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
─  running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
─  using session charset: ASCII
✔  checking for file 'elementR/DESCRIPTION' ...
─  checking extension type ... Package
─  this is package 'elementR' version '1.3.7'
✔  checking package namespace information
✔  checking package dependencies (4.2s)
✔  checking if this is a source package
✔  checking if there is a namespace
✔  checking for executable files ...
✔  checking for hidden files and directories ...
✔  checking for portable file names
✔  checking for sufficient/correct file permissions
✔  checking whether package 'elementR' can be installed (33.9s)
✔  checking installed package size ...
✔  checking package directory
W  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
   During startup - Warning messages:
   1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
   2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
   3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
   4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
   5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
   6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
    ERROR
   During startup - Warning messages:
   1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
   2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
   3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
   4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
   5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
   6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
   
   See
     '/tmp/Rtmpv5TXJD/file1a37e877283/elementR.Rcheck/00check.log'
   for details.
   
   
── R CMD check results ────────────────────────────── elementR 1.3.7 ────
Duration: 40.7s

❯ checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... WARNING
  During startup - Warning messages:
  1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
  2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
  3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
  4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
  5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
  6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
   ERROR
  During startup - Warning messages:
  1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
  2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
  3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
  4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
  5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
  6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 

❯ checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... WARNING
  During startup - Warning messages:
  1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
  2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
  3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
  4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
  5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
  6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
   ERROR
  During startup - Warning messages:
  1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
  2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
  3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
  4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
  5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
  6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 

1 error ✖ | 1 warning ✖ | 0 notes ✔
```

and on the log, it seems that it is just the same :

```
* using log directory '/tmp/Rtmpv5TXJD/file1a37e877283/elementR.Rcheck'
* using R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
* using platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
* R was compiled by
    gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
    GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
* running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
* using session charset: ASCII
* checking for file 'elementR/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package 'elementR' version '1.3.7'
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package 'elementR' can be installed ... OK
* checking installed package size ... OK
* checking package directory ... OK
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... WARNING
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
 ERROR
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR, 1 WARNING
```

Comment: This looks like an environment configuration problem: how are you running R? From the terminal? If so, run `locale` in your terminal and check its value. It should be something like `LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"` (plus more lines). Also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/9689104/1968, although the solution presented there is a brute-force hack, and should not be necessary on a properly configured system.

Comment: Thanks Rudolph, same error in R terminal and with regular linux terminal. locale CMD returns 
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
Just a different language I guess but I dont see any mistake in here.

Comment: I then execute defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8. and check the package again. No improvement. LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 R CMD check --as-cran elementR_1.3.7.tar.gz neither... snif