# R: Have I imported the rtracklayer package?

Tags: r, package

I have tried to search for this. And I think I might have to change proxy settings in R or something. But I am not sure if I can use the package "rtracklayer" or not? Thanks!

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
BiocInstaller version 1.4.7, ?biocLite for help
> biocLite("rtracklayer")
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using R version 2.15, BiocInstaller version 1.4.7.
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://brainarray.mbni.med.umich.edu/bioc/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.15
Installing package(s) 'rtracklayer'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://brainarray.mbni.med.umich.edu/bioc/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.15
trying URL 'http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.15/rtracklayer_1.16.3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1963816 bytes (1.9 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.9 Mb

tar: Failed to set default locale

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/18/_8lq3d811h379dld563yxbyc0000gr/T//RtmpsRfkls/downloaded_packages
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://brainarray.mbni.med.umich.edu/bioc/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.15
```

UPDATE: The packages seems to be working fine once they are loaded, so I don't really know if there is something wrong or not...

Comment: In essence a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907719/r-fail-install-packagesncstats-http-www-rforge-net-tar-failed-t) ?

Comment: @Jon, are you using Mac OS X?

Comment: @Martin, could be, but I think the other post was about dependencies. And I don't think that is the case here.

Comment: @Paul, yes I am using Mac OS X 10.7. And I came across something about proxy settings when searching for this problem.

Comment: The unusual part of your post is `tar: Failed to set default locale`,  the question I reference also suffers from this, and the response indicates a solution involving setting the locale on Macs (forcing it to run in US English).