# Strange locale problems in RStudio after update to OsX Mojave

Tags: r, rstudio, locale, macos-mojave

I'm having strange problems with R after updating to OsX Mojave.

When I start up a RStudio project I get:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C"
```

Than, if I `source()` R files raise an error if I don't remove the `encoding = 'UTF-8'` option if there are non-english characters like accented vowels.

Finally, the same characters if I use the View function get encoded, so `àèòù` become `<c3><a0><c3><a8><c3><b2><c3><b9>`

How can I solve this? it's pretty annoying expecially when save/sourcing R files from RStudio, since it puts `encoding = 'UTF-8'` by default.

UPDATE: the problem seems to be RStudio specific. Using plain R I don't get any errors.

Comment: Please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612835/strange-locale-problems-in-rstudio-after-update-to-osx-mojave

Answer (score 2):

The same problem appears on my laptop too.
However, it is not the first time that r-studio locale kinks after new MAC OS release.

[How to fix 'tar: Failed to set default locale' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907719/how-to-fix-tar-failed-to-set-default-locale-error)

The link above, which was created 8 years ago, solved this problem with one line of code:

```
system('defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8')
```

Also I found your related github issue. Seems a new update of r-studio fixed this problem. 
Either an update or running the code above will help.

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3587

Comment: Actually it wasn't enough! I posted an issue on RStudio github and the made a patch that will be out in v1.2 I think (I'm using a daily development version right now)